# SCSSの記法で出てくる $this: & !global; の意味は？

Tags: html, css, html5, sass

以下の記事で紹介されているBEM記法に `$this: & !global;` という記法が見られるのですが、どういう意味でしょうか？

[BEMのmodifierでスタイルを切り替える時の書き方 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/resistance_gowy/items/282363caa748f42e38dc)

**scss**

```
.p-hoge{
  $this: & !global;
  display:flex;
  background-color:#f00;
  &--reverse{
    background-color:#00f;
  }
}
.p-hoge__photo{
  width:100px;
  #{$this}--reverse &{
    order:1;
  }
}
.p-hoge__text{
  font-size:1.5rem;
  #{$this}--reverse &{
      order:0;
  }
}
```

**scssをcssにコンパイルすると下記のcssが出来ました。**

```
.p-hoge {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #f00;
}

.p-hoge--reverse {
  background-color: #00f;
}

.p-hoge__photo {
  width: 100px;
}

.p-hoge--reverse .p-hoge__photo {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
      -ms-flex-order: 1;
          order: 1;
}

.p-hoge__text {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.p-hoge--reverse .p-hoge__text {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
      -ms-flex-order: 0;
          order: 0;
}
```

おそらく変数の中には`.p-hoge`が入っているように見えます。しかしscssで変数の前に#を付けたり、あのような書き方があるのを知りませんでした。公式のドキュメントなどにも書かれているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まず `$this: & !global;` は、 `<variable>: <expression>` の形式であり、 `$this` という名称の**変数を定義している**とわかります<sup>[[1]](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables)</sup>。次に、ここで用いられているアンパサンド (`&`) は Sass における**親セレクター**です。親セレクターはネストされたステートメントにおいて、その親に相当するステートメントのセレクタに置き換えられます<sup>[[2]](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector)</sup>。つまり、以下のコードではアンパサンドは **`.p-hoge`** となります。

```
.p-hoge {
  $this: & !global;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #f00;
  &--reverse {
    background-color: #00f;
  }
}
```

最後に `!global` は **`!global` フラグ**と呼ばれています。`!global` フラグが設定された変数宣言はグローバルスコープにて変数宣言が行った場合と同様に、**変数のスコープが最上位**となります<sup>[[1]](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables)</sup>。たとえば、次のコードのコンパイル結果として、 **`.p-hoge`** および **`.p-hoge__photo`** クラスが作成されます。

```
.p-hoge {
  $this: & !global;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #f00;
}

#{$this}__photo {
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。変数のスコープが上位になるという事はp-hogeの外側でも変数が使用できるようになるという事ですね。

Comment: @wataru さん> はい、その理解で合っていると思います。